# Function minimum and maximum - are metrics?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and let  $d_1(x,y) = \mbox{max} (|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|)$. Is it true that this function is metric? I have only problem with triangle inequality. I suppose that it is metric because I can't find counterexample. But I have no idea how can I prove it?

And I have the same question for $d_2(x,y) = \mbox{min} (|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|)$

Comment: Counterexample for $d_2$: $x=(x_1, x_2)$ and $y=(x_1, y_2)$ with $x_2 \ne y_2$.

Comment: Can you show that $||x|| := \max(|x_1|, |x_2|)$ is a norm?